# How do I encrypt Macbook?

Tags: macos, encryption, filevault

How do I encrypt my MacBook, I have a windows computer for which I use BitLocker is there something similar for Apple?

Macbook Pro
Running MacOs Mojave

I'm looking to encrypt my entire mac

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault & https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204837 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105320/ are relevant.

Comment: Which MacBook model do you have, which version of macOS is it running?

Comment: Also, are you asking a general question out of curiosity or are you looking for ways to encrypt your current MacBook?

Answer (score 2):

See [this support article](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204837) for how to encrypt your startup disk.